# Can we write below code in more optimize way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

By these line of code I am trying to drop an entire row from dataframe which doesn't contains a string '-->' in any column values.

```
try:
    for j in range(len(df)):
        flg = 0
        for i in df.columns:
            if df[i].astype(str).str.contains('-->').iloc[j]:
                flg = 1
        if flg == 0:
            df.drop(df.index[j], axis=0, inplace=True)
except:
    pass
```

This is a working code. The question is can we write this piece of code in more optimized way as this code is taking more time if we have 20K or more rows in dataframe.

Comment: How many possible non strings columns? Or all columns are strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could vectorize:

```py
mask = df.astype(str).apply(lambda column : column.str.contains('-->')).any(axis=1)
df = df[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

Select only `object` columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and test if exist `-->` substrings, numeric and datetimes columns are not tested and filter all rows where it least one value matched by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('-->')).any(axis=1)]
```

Or convert all columns to strings, it should be slowier, because tested all columns (also numeric without substring `-->`):

```
df = df[df.astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('-->')).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Do you need to cast as `str` before calling a `str.contains` method?

Comment: Okay noted, reading his example my solution assumes every entry of the frame is a string.

Comment: indeed, have updated my solution to your comment

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is giving me an expected result. But I am surprised, how this code actually works (as I am new in python)

Comment: @AnuragGupta - Is not more faster first solution `df = df[df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('-->')).any(axis=1)]` like second? Because solution above should be slovier, explained in my answer. Only one answer should be accepted, not both.

Comment: @AnuragGupta - do you think no explanation in second answer? Because I add explanation for my both solutions.

Comment: @AnuragGupta - if something should be explained more, let me know.